# Installing new Body Control Module

Tags: bcm

I recently bought a new BCM for a 2009 Infiniti FX50S. On installing new BCM, there was total blackout; no more ignition light. How can I programme the new BCM to work with my car?

Comment: What is the year/make/model/option package of the car? There is no way to answer this question without background on the vehicle itself.

Comment: Also, expand acronyms in the title and when they are first used - what is a BCM?

Comment: The suspense was killing me - [Body Control Module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Body_control_module).

Comment: @JPhi1618 - Please feel free to update questions as such ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Initializing a BCM for your vehicle requires a special Nissan dealership tool.**

This is a theft prevention measure in order to thwart criminals from plugging in a BCM and stealing the vehicle.

The BCM contains information related to digital key security related to the key fob.

The BCM has a serial number that would be required to be entered into the initialization device which then issues a PIN you put into a software application that will initialize the BCM for the first time.  Following initialization and installation a new fob would need to be associated with the device.

***You will need to goto an Infiniti or Nissan dealership or a shop that has the appropriate tools to perform this task.***

[PDF explaining the procedure](http://www.adusa.us/attachments/File/Updated_NISSAN_FOR_WEB-3-1-13.pdf)